# Does installing .NET Framework 4.6.2 on a server resets IIS running application pools?

Tags: iis, installation, .net, application-pools, dotnet-framework

On our production data center we have IIS Pools running on ASP.NET 2.0.

We need to install new WebApps on these servers but they use .NET Framework 4.6.2. We can not stop our IIS Pools, and yet we need to install the new Framework for these new apps to run.

Does anyone know/have a solid evidence that I can install the Framework without reseting any running application Pool? Or should I look for a deployment Window? (and that means after Christmas).

**EDIT**
.Net Framework 4.5 is already installed on these servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I tried by my own, keep navigating in an ASP.NET Pool 2.0 website and launch .NET 4.6.2 installation.

In some machines the pools were actually reset. In the worse case scenarios, some machines actually asked me to reset. So there is no way to install on servers that we cannot have a planned stop.